# what is the significance of $ref in Odata 4

Tags: odata

I am bit new to OData world

1. can someone help me understand what does $ref signifies in OData 4,
2. what is difference between $ref and $expand ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ananth

The $expand system query option specifies the related resources or media streams to be included in line with retrieved resources.
You can refer to https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/cs01/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.01-cs01-part2-url-conventions.html#sec_SystemQueryOptionexpand for $expand detail.

The $ref is a path segment which is used to address references between entities.
You can refer to: https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/cs01/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.01-cs01-part2-url-conventions.html#sec_AddressingReferencesbetweenEntities for $ref detail.

Comment: Hi, Sam Xu can you elaborate more on address references between entities ?

Comment: @ananthsharma did you understood it address references between entities

Comment: how should i be using $ref?